# How alert first car which will achieve the goal?

Tags: javascript

if (car1 > maxWidth || car2 > maxWidth || car3 > maxWidth || car4 > maxWidth || car5> maxWidth)

alert(car1 > car2 ? 'Winner car1' : 'Winner car2');

Comment: Hi boban, can you please read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post accordingly? Right now you have no explanation at all, just a title and a block of code, and that does not constitution a question (yet). Explain the problem in terms of what you needed to do, what you did (you're already showing that part), what that does and why that isn't what you expected it to do, and then finally what you already tried in order to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried this alert(car1 > car2 ? 'Winner car1' : 'Winner car2');  but this is just for car1 and car2. I want from all cars up to alert just only one with the maxWith.

Comment: Dude you gotta format your question better, adding a comment with a random test doesn't help. Ready what @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans wrote

Answer (score 0):

How to figure out not only which score won, but who did that score belong to.  There are two pieces of data, car name and score.

A good functional programming approach would be to structure those cars in an array, and use an array function to calculate the winner, in this case array.reduce.

```js
// you have this part somewhere already
var car1 = 10, car2 = 20, car3 = 15, car4 = 33, car5 = 2;
var maxWidth = 12; // gotta be more than this wide to win

// make an array
var cars = [car1, car2, car3, car4, car5];

// reduce the array to find the winner
var winner = cars.reduce((leader, curr, i) => {
  if (curr > leader.width)
    return {width: curr, name: "car" + (i + 1)};
  
  return leader;
}, {width: maxWidth, name: "nobody"}); // set "nobody" as the initial leader

console.log(winner.name + " wins!");
```

Comment: мore precisely when the car will reach the destination, the first one will be alerted.

Comment: Ah so there's a time component, a *when*.  You will need to be even more precise and edit your exact scenario into your question!